# How can I fix this error I get on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I open an application that I've been building on heroku, I get an application error when I go to the signup page. I went into my heroku logs, and found this error message:

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.5ms)
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `time_zone' for #):

Here is my view for creating a new user:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset4">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :phone_number, "Your cell phone number" %>
        <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password confirmation" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

        <%= f.label :time_zone, "Choose your time zone" %>
        <%= f.select :time_zone, [['Eastern'], ['Central'], ['Mountain'], ['Pacific']] %><br>

    <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

What might be causing this error, and how can I go about fixing it? Thanks so much!

```
  def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
 sign_in @user
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to app!"
 redirect_to info_path
else
  render 'new'
end
```

end

def new
    @user = User.new
  end

Comment: Does `@user` have a `time_zone` attribute?

Comment: Yes it does. In my user model I have the following code: attr_accessible :time_zone

Comment: `attr_accessible :time_zone` is not the an attribute definition for `:time_zone`. Can you open `rails console` in shell and run `u = User.new; u.time_zone` without getting an error? This assumes in your view `@user` is an instance of a model named `User`.

Comment: I don't get an error when running that piece of code in rails console. All I get is nil.

Comment: Sure, I'll add the create action from my user controller right now.

Comment: Okay, sorry about. I'll post it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you migrate your database after pushing to heroku

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

heroku have logs just like your rails server on development, you can run heroku logs and tail it.  This should give you good insights on what line and what action caused the error